# istio - sidecar initialization delay causing health checks failure

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar

I am seeing quite a bit of a lag in sidecar startup.

istio-proxy version 1.9.1
wondering if `readiness.status.sidecar.istio.io/initialDelaySeconds: '25'` I added as a pod annotation is contributing to this ?

Notice between citadelclient and "marking server ready" there is some 31 seconds.

```
.068623Z     info    CA Endpoint istiod.istio-system.svc:15012, provider Citadel
2023-04-07T16:17:14.068669Z     info    Using CA istiod.istio-system.svc:15012 cert with certs: var/run/secrets/istio/root-cert.pem
2023-04-07T**16:17:14**.068788Z     info    citadelclient   Citadel client using custom root cert: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2023-04-07T16:**17:15.37**0678Z     info    ads     All caches have been synced up in 1.402092063s, marking server ready
2023-04-07T16:17:15.370934Z     info    sds     SDS server for workload certificates started, listening on "./etc/istio/proxy/SDS"
2023-04-07T16:17:15.370962Z     info    xdsproxy        Initializing with upstream address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" and cluste
r "Kubernetes"
2023-04-07T16:17:15.370981Z     info    sds     Start SDS grpc server
2023-04-07T16:17:15.371133Z     info    Starting proxy agent
2023-04-07T16:17:15.371195Z     info    Opening status port 15020
2023-04-07T16:17:15.468216Z     info    Received new config, creating new Envoy epoch 0
2023-04-07T16:17:15.468289Z     info    Epoch 0 startin
```

Also Notice between Envoy Command and "xdsproxy        connected"

```
2023-04-07T16:17:16.168679Z     info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --pare
nt-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster REDACTED1 --service-node sidecar~192.168.114.88~REDACTED2-785f49b95
7-hdvc2.REDACTED3.svc.cluster.local --local-address-ip-version v4 --bootstrap-version 3 --log-for
mat %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ     %l      envoy %n        %v -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]misc:error --concurrency 2]
2023-04-07T16:17:20.568742Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min
_size
2023-04-07T16:17:20.568801Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min
_size
2023-04-07T16:17:20.668331Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min
_size
2023-04-07T16:17:20.668390Z     warning envoy runtime   Unable to use runtime singleton for feature envoy.http.headermap.lazy_map_min
_size
2023-04-07T16:17:23.771528Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
```

Comment: Istio 1.9 is out of support for long time now: https://istio.io/latest/docs/releases/supported-releases/#support-status-of-istio-releases
I'd recommend you to use a supported version and come back with questions on it.